# Python FloorOfX Using Binary Search

Tags: python, search, binary, floor

How do I write the code by using binary search:

```
def floorofx(L, x):
    pass
```

Like define low, high, middle for each of element. As,

```
Input: L = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 20, 27, 28], x = 17
Output: 15
```

15 is the largest element in `L` smaller than 17.

```
Input: L = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 19], x = 20
Output: 19
```

19 is the largest element in `L` smaller than 20.

```
Input: L = [1, 2, 8, 10, 10, 12, 19], x = 0
Output: -1
```

Since floor doesn't exist, output is -1.

Can someone help me with it?

Comment: What if `-1` is an element of `L`?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#module-bisect) module and decrement the obtained index.

```
from bisect import bisect_right

def floorofx(L, x):
    idx = bisect_right(L,x)
    return L[idx-1] if idx > 0 else -1
```

This generates the following results (for your given sample input):

```
>>> floorofx(L = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 20, 27, 28], x = 17)
15
>>> floorofx(L = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 19], x = 20)
19
>>> floorofx(L = [1, 2, 8, 10, 10, 12, 19], x = 0)
-1
```

Mind that **`L` must be sorted**, and that in case **`-1` is an element of `L`**, you cannot make the **distinction between "not found" and -1 as a result**. Since we use *binary search*, the algorithm runs in *O(log n)*.

Comment: It returns -1 instead of 0    In this case     L = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110]
        self.assertEqual(floorofx(L, 0), 0)

Comment: @WentaoHu: and this is fixed one second ago.